# fclose, fopen and fwrite issues with writing multiple files

Tags: c++, file-io, fopen, fwrite, fclose

I have a program that records data from a serial port. Every so often, I want to split up files such that the data logs don't become very large. The problem is, after I recreate the FILE* and try to write into it, the program crashes. No compiler errors/warnings before hand also...

The program does create one log for the first time interval, but once it's time to create a new data log, it crashes at the fwrite.

First off, initializations/declarations.

```
char * DATA_DIR = "C:\DATA";
sprintf(path,"%s%s%s",DATA_DIR,curtime,".log"); //curtime is just the current time in a string
FILE * DATA_LOG = fopen(path, "wb+");
```

And later on in a while loop

```
if(((CURRENT_TIME-PREVIOUS_TIME) > (SEC_IN_MINUTE * MINUTE_CHUNKS) ) && (MINUTE_CHUNKS != 0) && FIRST_TIME == 0) //all this does is just checks if its time to make a new file
{
    fclose(DATA_LOG); //end the current fileread

    char * path; 
    char curtime[16];

    //gets the current time and saves it to a file name
    sprintf(curtime , "%s" , currentDateTime());
    sprintf(path,"%s%s%s",DATA_DIR,curtime,".log");

    DATA_LOG = fopen(path, "wb+"); //open the new file

    //just some logic (not relevant to problem)
    PREVIOUS_TIME = CURRENT_TIME; 
    newDirFlag = 1;
}
fwrite(cdata , sizeof(char) , numChars , DATA_LOG); //crashes here. cdata, sizeof, and numChars don't change values
```

Any ideas why is this happening? I'm stumped.

Comment: are you checking the return values of fopen and fwrite and others?

Comment: is this C++ or simply C?

Comment: On a different note, declaring char * path without any size or dynamic allocation may have unwanted side effects.

Comment: This is in C++. No, I haven't checked the return values. I will do that right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your MAIN problem is that `char * path;` has no memory assigned to it. This means that you are writing to some RANDOM [1] location in memory.

I would suggest that you use `char path[PATH_MAX];` - that way you don't have to worry about allocating and later deallocating the storage for your path.

Alternatively, you could use:

```
stringstream ss;

ss << DATA_DIR << currentDateTime() << ".log";
string path = ss.str();
fopen(path.c_str(), "wb+")
```

which is a more C++ style solution.

[1] By random, I don't mean truly a random number, but some unknown value that happens to be in that location on the stack. It is almost always NOT a good place to store a string.

Comment: I wound up doing this. Ultimately I found out that my problem was that my path string somehow did change and that messed up my fopen. I learned a lot from this post/googling from it.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of problems, path has no memory allocated (you're writing stuff to some random memory address which is bad). You also should check the return values of `fwrite` `fopen` for errors. If there is one use `perror` so you know what the problem is. It's likely the fopen is failing or you're corrupting your stack by writing to `path`.

Also use `snprintf` it's much safter than just `sprintf` which is vulnerable to buffer overflow.

EDIT: just saw your comment that it's c++. Why not use `std::string` and `fstream` instead? They are much safer than what you're currently doing (and probably easier).

Comment: Apologies. I don't have any formal experience in C++ (only Java). I'm changing code written by a previous intern, so I didn't know about fstream since he didn't use it in this code.

Are you saying that instead of char * path; I can do something like std:string path? I wouldn't need to worry about the random memory address issue?

Comment: Yes, `std::string` will handle allocating memory for the string and such so you don't have to worry about making `char path[512];` or something to hold the path. You can always pass the underlying string by calling `my_string.c_str()` if you still want to use `fopen` and such.